# How to write from all the file from child to parent using time?

Tags: c, linux, pipe

I have written the following code in c, the parent read what he get from child using pipe, and write it to a new file, and the child should wait between each 50 characters he read but the problem is that parent only write one line to the file, I know there is something missing but unable to recognize it?

```
  if(fork())
  {
    //Parent
    read(fd[0],str,sizeof(str));
    fprintf(fpnew,str,"w+");
  }
  else
  {
    //Child 1
    while(fgets(str,n,fp)!=NULL)
    { 
      write(fd[1],str,sizeof(str));
      sleep(1+rand()%10);
    }
  }
```

Comment: What's the actual problem you're trying to solve?  The code you've posted is missing key components, like what is `fp`.

Comment: no not that, but the parent only write one line to the file, I want him to write all the child file?

Comment: And you should always keep the result of `fork()` and handle all three cases `<0` (failure), `==0` (child process), `>0` (parent process, and you should later `wait` for the resulting `pid_t`....). You might lack some calls to `fflush`. And you should show more code!

Comment: and fix the indentation...

Comment: Well the parent is only *reading* one line from the child (sort of, maybe) so that's going to be a problem in writing more than that to the file.

Comment: Yes that's it, so how can the parent read all the lines from child?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put a loop in the parent to read the child output until it is finished.  `fprintf` is the wrong thing to use here.  If you want to stick to the std C lib then you probably want `fwrite` here.  But rather than mix and match the stdlib functions with the lower level read I tend to like to be consistent.  It's just one less thing to think about.  You want something more like this.  (Also, read up on the parameters of the functions you are using and check return code.)

```
  int fpnew = open("whatever", O_WRONLY);
  if (pfnew < 0)
      error....

  int bytesread;

  while ((bytesread = read(fd[0], str, sizeof(str))) != 0)
      write(fpnew, str, bytesread);

  close(pfnew);
```